# Hadoop MapReduce - Reducer with small number of keys and many values per key

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-analysis

Hadoop is naturally created to work with Big data. But what happens if you're output from Mappers is also big, too big to fit to Reducers memory?

Let's say we're considering some large amount of data that we want to cluster. We use some partitioning algorithm, that will find specified number of "groups" of elements (clusters), such that elements in one cluster are similar, but elements that belong to different clusters are dissimilar. Number of clusters often needs to be specified.

If I try to implement K-means as best known clustering algorithm, one iteration would look like this:

- Map phase - assign objects to closest centroids
- Reduce phase - calculate new centroids based on all objects in a cluster

But what happens if we have only two clusters?

In that case, the large dataset will be divided into two parts, and there would be only two keys and for each of the keys values would contain half of the large dataset.

What I don't understand is - what if the Reducer gets many values for one key? How can he fit it in its RAM?? Isn't this one of the things why Hadoop was created?

I gave just an example of an algorithm, but this is a general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisely the reason why in the Reducer you never get a List of the values for a particular key. You only get an Iterator for the values. If the number of values for a particular key are too many they are not stored in memory but values are read off the local disk.

Links: [Reducer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Reducer)

Also please see Secondary Sort which is a very useful design pattern when you have scenario where there are too many values.

Comment: Thanks. Can I see more about this topic somewhere?